# PouchDb.get(id,{attachments: true}) not returning data on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I am developing an Ionic App using PouchDb (No replication). I am able to store data with attachments successfully.

To retrieve the data, I use the controller snippet below to call the get function in an angularjs factory,

```
pouchDbManager.getData(currentSongIdx).then(function(result) {
        $scope.songs.push({title:result.title,image:result.image}); 
       audioFile=$sce.trustAsUrl("data:audio/mp3;base64,"+result._attachments.song.data);
        $scope.playCurrentSong(audioFile); 
        if(result.sermon_favourite == 1) {$scope.favourited = 1}
    });
```

The factory snippet is below

```
.factory('pouchDbManager', function($q) {
   ......
   function getData(id){
        return $q.when(_db.get(id,{attachments: true}));
    }
   ......
  }
```

The snippets above work perfectly in my chrome browser returning data and the expected attachment. But when I build the project and run it on my android device, no data is returned.

With a bit of console logging, I discovered the getData function in the factory wasn't returning data.

I also used pouchdb.get(id) and pouchdb.getAttachment(id, filename).

While both functions also worked optimally on Chrome, pouchdb.getAttachment failed to return expected attachment on my android device.

The attachment is stored in base64 and its about 10-15mb

Has anybody experienced this issue? Kindly help out

I am developing with Ionic, AngularJs, Pouchdb 5.3.1, Cordova, Android 4.4.2 with 2GB Ram.

Comment: Are you using the SQLite Plugin? Crosswalk Plugin? Also a test to reproduce would be helpful; we have lots of tests on attachments and have never seen anything weird happening with Android.