# "big" attachement over pouchdb with sqlite froze

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, pouchdb

When using PouchDB with Cordova on an Android 8 device (without crosswalk plugin), getAttachement never answer on file bigger than 1 or 2MB.
By "never answer", I mean that my promise never resolves (nor success nor failure). FYI: tiny attachments works perfectly.

Version :

- android: 8 (on a galaxy s8)
- cordova: 8 (with android platform 6.4.0)
- cordova-plugin-sqlite-2: 1.0.4
- pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite: 2.0.3
- pouchdb: 6.4.3

This request is like this one : [PouchDb.get(id,{attachments: true}) not returning data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603438/pouchdb-getid-attachments-true-not-returning-data-on-android)

My reputation is not big enough to comment on it adding details that may help some to understand / reproduce it. So please, do not flag it as "duplicate" ;)

Comment: Did you try without the sqlite adapter ? I had the same problem and going to indexeddb was my way to get rid of it.

Comment: Thx for the hint but I need to go with sqlite because I cannot afford the size limitation of others available databases.

Comment: Actually it is a bit confusing and hard to know about the size limitation, what I finally understood is that indexeddb was actually done to store large amount of data and for recent browser the size limitation is fixed by a quota (50% of available space left in firefox). It seems that indexeddb improve quickly, perhaps that is why the documentation is so confusing..? Here a question about that : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/is-the-indexeddb-api-available-to-an-ionic-3-pwa-running-on-an-ipad/106405

Comment: Thank you for that, I know have a better view on this. But this open issue : [pouchdb issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7241) confort me on my sqlite direction. (+ the fact that once the project is features complete, I will try to run it on ios as well. Production aims the two platforms.

Comment: for anyone interested in the answer, I opened an issue on pouchdb repository ([here](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/7285)). I will post an answer once I have one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the final answer : it is a known android limitation which relates to an already answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406429/cursor-size-limit-in-android-sqlitedatabase).